# WPF loading panel and UI freeze

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface, freeze

I have a mainwindow which displays a 'Please wait' panel containing a loading gif whenever I do some work in a Task. The gif plays fine when the data is being compiled, but when the INPC logic to refresh the UI controls is being executed (thus on the main UI thread), the app freezes for a split second and my gif does not play smoothly anymore.

For instance, I am following the MVVM pattern, I have a datagrid in my view which is binded to an ObservableCollection MyBindedCollection. In the constructor of my viewmodel which runs in a Task, I create a tmp observable collection and when the process is finished, I set the variable MyBindedCollection to tmp (thus not adding one by one my items to it). The INPC logic is of course in the setter of my property MyBindedCollection.

Is there anyway to prevent this? any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some minimal code? Are you following MVVM patterns? E.g. it often is better to minimize notifications on the UI thread. Instead of doing Add() in a loop collections with AddRange() will do the adding in a single notification.

Comment: @ZoolWay I edited my OP with an example. I am not doing anything fancy, however, when binding a great amount of items, it freezes the UI. When i limit the size of the datagrid, it freezes less (less items to display in the UI).

Comment: Have you tried instead of exchanging the ObservableCollection to use `MyBindedCollection.AddRange(tmp)`? Also have you set `EnableRowVirtualization` and tried both values?

Comment: @ZoolWay I tried switching to a list, addRange did not do the trick. EnableRowVirtualiation set to true seems to improve the situation by a little bit, but I still get a freeze.

Comment: On how many records are we talking here and on a freeze of how long? Can you use `Stopwatch` to check the duration on the UI thread when applying the data from the `Task`? A very very small freeze cannot be avoided as the UI thread has to do something...

Comment: @ZoolWay yes, no way around that I'm affraid. I'll just fade out my wait panel and thread.Wait enough time for the animation to finish before displaying my content. Thus it'll appear smooth. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the wait is still big and many rows, you could always do some compromise. Like push 20 records to the View which the user can see immediately, than wait a bit in the background thread and push more and more data. Might need some experimentation - and you should think if it would be really worth your time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ZoolWay yes, no way around that I'm affraid. I'll just fade out my wait panel and thread.Wait enough time for the animation to finish before displaying my content. Thus it'll appear smooth. Thanks for your time.